# ng-include inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat and inside it an include for a different html partial.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in feedItems">
  <div ng-include="'item.itemType.html'">
  </div>
</div>
```

For example if the itemType=40 it shows the 40.html, if it's 80 it shows the 80.html (The names of the partial will be fixed but for now lets keep it simple):

So far so good. My problem is now that I need to keep using data from item inside the partial html. Also every partial has a dedicated controller but I believe that is doable by adding ng-controller in each ng-include.

For example: My 40.html partial contains:

40.html:

```
<span>{{item.body.text}}</span>
```

80.html:

```
<h1>{{item.message.text}}</span>
```

I'm not even sure if what I want to achieve is even possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done this and run into a problem? What you describe should work fine. The ng-include creates a child scope which prototypically inherits from the scope created in ng-repeat. References in 80.html to {{item.message.text}} should work just fine. Prototypical inheritance can cause some unexpected results at times, especially when you're dealing with primitives rather than objects; however, your example shouldn't run afoul of such things. What problem(s) or unexpected behavior(s) are you seeing? If you're having problems, can you add some more code and/or a Plnkr?

Comment: It was only a theory. And now i'm getting an error because item.itemType is not converting to 80 or 40

Answer (score 0):

The ng-include creates a child scope which prototypically inherits from the scope created in ng-repeat. References in 80.html to {{item.message.text}} should work just fine, as there is no "item" defined on that child scope, so it will follow the inheritance chain up and find "item" on the parent (or parent's parent) scope.

Prototypical inheritance can cause some unexpected results at times, especially when you're dealing with primitives rather than objects; however, the example you showed doesn't appear that it will run afoul of such things.